# change font name of google fonts to match definition in svg

Tags: css, svg, fonts, font-family, google-fonts

I have this svg that I use in my html:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(1 1)">
        <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="15" stroke="#BBD1DD" stroke-width="2"/>
        <text fill="#F83A32" font-family="FiraSans-Medium, Fira Sans" font-size="14" font-weight="400">
            <tspan x="12" y="19">1</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

note, I have probably around 100 svgs like this, receive them from a designer, and constantly things change and I receive new ones and have to replace old ones

now the problem:

The font family / name `FiraSans-Medium` does not exist with that name.

Thus, the icon renders the wrong font.

Probably the right font would be Fira Sans with weight 500.

I include my fonts like this:

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:200,500|Fira+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,500" rel="stylesheet">
```

now is there an easy way to remap the font so that I don't have to edit hundred of svg files manually and each time on change?

Answer (score 2):

The file you are referencing is no more than a stylesheet. You can download that file and include it from your own server, rewriting the used name:

```
/* ...more @font-face rules... */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans'; /* replace with 'FiraSans-Medium' */
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Fira Sans Medium'), local('FiraSans-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/firasans/v8/zM2u8V3CuPVwAAXFQcDi4Ogdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
```

As an aside: While `FiraSans-Medium` is listed in the stylesheet as the local name for `font-weight="500"`, the `font-weight="400"` defined in the svg is listed there as `FiraSans-Regular`. But that you will have to take up with your designer.

Comment: what a bummer it doesn't seem to work even with that... seems like svgs cannot pick up custom fonts like that.
see here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXNrmX

Comment: follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46897973/img-src-x-svg-make-svg-pick-up-the-font-face-defined-by-me-aka-font-family

Comment: In that pen, you are loading the svg with an `<img>` tag, which means in a separate context that has no access to the parent context stylesheet. That won't work.