# <img src='x.svg'> Make svg pick up the font face defined by me, aka font-family

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts, font-face

example code

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXNrmX)

HTML

`<img src="http://svgur.com/i/3Y2.svg">`

svg content

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(1 1)">
        <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="15" stroke="#BBD1DD" stroke-width="2"/>
        <text fill="#F83A32" font-family="FiraSans-Medium" font-size="14" font-weight="500">
            <tspan x="12" y="19">1</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
<head xmlns=""/></svg>
```

css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FiraSans-Medium';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Fira Sans Medium'), local('FiraSans-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/firasans/v8/zM2u8V3CuPVwAAXFQcDi4K-j2U0lmluP9RWlSytm3ho.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FiraSans-Medium';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Fira Sans Medium'), local('FiraSans-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/firasans/v8/zM2u8V3CuPVwAAXFQcDi4JX5f-9o1vgP2EXwfjgl7AY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FiraSans-Medium';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Fira Sans Medium'), local('FiraSans-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/firasans/v8/zM2u8V3CuPVwAAXFQcDi4BWV49_lSm1NYrwo-zkhivY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FiraSans-Medium';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Fira Sans Medium'), local('FiraSans-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/firasans/v8/zM2u8V3CuPVwAAXFQcDi4KaRobkAwv3vxw3jMhVENGA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FiraSans-Medium';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Fira Sans Medium'), local('FiraSans-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/firasans/v8/zM2u8V3CuPVwAAXFQcDi4P8zf_FOSsgRmwsS7Aa9k2w.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FiraSans-Medium';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Fira Sans Medium'), local('FiraSans-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/firasans/v8/zM2u8V3CuPVwAAXFQcDi4D0LW-43aMEzIO6XUTLjad8.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FiraSans-Medium';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Fira Sans Medium'), local('FiraSans-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/firasans/v8/zM2u8V3CuPVwAAXFQcDi4Ogdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
```

font is not picked up by svg file in chrome 59

Comment: According to my F12 Developer Tools, the rendered font is indeed Fira Sans. Are you sure it's not being rendered as that for you? The `1` looks almost identical.

Comment: but that's the font that is applied to the image tag. Not to the image svg content itself. And anyway, fira sans is _not_ the font I defined. I was requestin firasans-medium.